# How to get the contents between 2 parenthesis using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
(Boxing Bag@bag.jpg@To punch and kick)(Wallet@wallet.jpg@To keep money in)
```

How can I extract the contents within the parenthesis so I get 2 strings:

```
Boxing Bag@bag.jpg@To punch and kick
Wallet@wallet.jpg@To keep money in
```

What would be the regex for this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [suat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219681/how-to-get-the-contents-between-2-parenthesis-using-regex/7219702#7219702)'s regex, and since you want to do global matching with groups, you need to use a loop to get all the matches:

```
var str = '(Boxing Bag@bag.jpg@To punch and kick)(Wallet@wallet.jpg@To keep money in)';
var regex = new RegExp('\\((.*?)\\)', 'g');
var match, matches = [];
while(match = regex.exec(str))
    matches.push(match[1]);
alert(matches);
// ["Boxing Bag@bag.jpg@To punch and kick", "Wallet@wallet.jpg@To keep money in"]
```

Comment: The method demonstrated by cwallenpoole is faster, though, as it avoids backtracking to find the closing paren.

Answer (score 1):

This regex `/[^()]+/g` matches all series of characters which are not `(` or `)`:

```
var s = '(Boxing Bag@bag.jpg@To punch and kick)'+ // I broke this for readability
        '(Wallet@wallet.jpg@To keep money in)'.match(/[^()]+/g)
console.log(s) // ["Boxing Bag@bag.jpg@To punch and kick",
               //  "Wallet@wallet.jpg@To keep money in"]
```

Comment: This will also match `blah` in `(foo)blah(bar)`. That may or may not be a problem depending on what the OP knows about the input string.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little javascript library called **[balanced](https://github.com/icodeforlove/node-balanced)** to help with tasks like this. As mentioned by @Paulpro the solution breaks if you have content in between the parenthesis, which is what balanced is good at.

```
var source = '(Boxing Bag@bag.jpg@To punch and kick)Random Text(Wallet@wallet.jpg@To keep money in)';

var matches = balanced.matches({source: source, open: '(', close: ')'}).map(function (match) {
    return source.substr(match.index + match.head.length, match.length - match.head.length - match.tail.length);
});

// ["Boxing Bag@bag.jpg@To punch and kick", "Wallet@wallet.jpg@To keep money in"]
```

heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/YR7y5/) example